# Recent activity not showing here at Meta SO

Tags: support, recent-activity, up-votes

I got a couple of upvotes just now but it's not showing in the the recent activity page where I got those upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you click "today"? Sometimes the envelope can't figure out when you've been here exactly.

Comment: Nope. What's the default if it's not 'today'?